# Flutter Devtool / Inspector / Toggle widget mode: Widget selection work only one time

Tags: flutter, devtools

As said in the title, when I use the widget mode, I can only click one widget (it work).
When I click on another widget, nothing happens.
A workaroud is to disable/enable widget mode each time.
Any idea ?
I use the last SDK/Dart version.

```
Flutter 3.13.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ead455963c (11 days ago) • 2023-09-26 18:28:17 -0700
Engine • revision a794cf2681
Tools • Dart 3.1.3 • DevTools 2.25.0
```